# How to pass Catalog name in PySpark with literals?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to build a programmatic approach using PySpark to list all databases in all catalogs I have in Databricks. While I am able to do this manually using SQL, I would like to make it more robust using PySpark so that I can automate it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
list_catalogs = ['100sandbox', '200playground', '1000', 'sales']

df_catalogs_and_databases = None
_df = None

for catalog in list_catalogs:
    _df = spark.sql(f'SHOW DATABASES FROM {catalog}')\
        .select(
            lit(catalog).alias('catalog'),
            col('databaseName').alias('database')
        )
    try:
        df_catalogs_and_databases = df_catalogs_and_databases.union(_df)
    except AttributeError as e:
        # Catching this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'union'
        df_catalogs_and_databases = _df
    except Exception as e:
        raise

display(df_catalogs_and_databases)
```

I am getting the below error upon running the above code:

> [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '100'.(line 1, pos 20)

Answer (score 0):

- The ERROR is because you are trying to create a database named "**1000**" directly this might result in an error.
- In SQL, database,Table names cannot start with a numerical digit. They must start with a letter or an underscore.

I have tried the below and received the similar ERROR Like you.

I have listed catalogs like this.

```
list_catalogs = ['100sandbox', '200playground', '1000', 'sales']
```

**ERROR:**

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '1000'.(line 1, pos 20)

== SQL ==
SHOW DATABASES FROM 1000
```

Then I have listed like below:

```
list_catalogs = ['100sandbox', '200playground', 'db_1000', 'sales']
dilip_df = spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES") \
    .select(
        lit("all_catalogs").alias('catalog'),
        col('databaseName').alias('database')
    )
dilip_df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+------------+-------------+
|catalog     |database     |
+------------+-------------+
|all_catalogs|100sandbox   |
|all_catalogs|200playground|
|all_catalogs|db_1000      |
|all_catalogs|default      |
|all_catalogs|sales        |
+------------+-------------+
```

I have tried the below approach:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
list_catalogs = ['100sandbox', '200playground', 'db_1000', 'sales']
schema = StructType([
    StructField("catalog", StringType(), True),
    StructField("database", StringType(), True),
])
df_catalogs_and_databases = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
for catalog in list_catalogs:
    databases = spark.catalog.listDatabases(catalog)
     _df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(catalog, db.name) for db in databases],
        schema
    )
    df_catalogs_and_databases = df_catalogs_and_databases.unionAll(_df)
df_catalogs_and_databases.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------------+-------------+
|catalog      |database     |
+-------------+-------------+
|100sandbox   |100sandbox   |
|200playground|200playground|
|db_1000      |db_1000      |
|sales        |sales        |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I guess you have mistaken database for catalog. My list is talking only about catalogs and I do have many catalogs today in my system that just have numeric characters and no alpha characters.

Comment: Are you using Databricks untiy Catalog?

Comment: Yes, I am using Databricks Unity Catalog.

Comment: I am using Azure databricks the catalogs that are created are stored in Hivemeta store and they can be view via catalog explorer and as you mentioned you are using the databricks unity catalog let me try that at my end once again and will update you

Comment: I appended the literal value to my catalog names so that it works. I posted my complete solution above.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this worked out with the below solution:

```
df_catalogs = spark.sql('SHOW CATALOGS')\
    .select(
        concat(lit("`"), 'catalog', lit("`")).alias("catalog") #Concatenating literals for catalogs that have only numeric characters
        )


list_catalogs = [row[0] for row in df_catalogs.collect()]

df_catalogs_and_databases = None
_df = None

for catalog in list_catalogs:
    _df = spark.sql(f'SHOW DATABASES FROM {catalog}')\
        .select(
            lit(catalog).alias('catalog'),
            col('databaseName').alias('database')
        )
    try:
        df_catalogs_and_databases = df_catalogs_and_databases.union(_df)
    except AttributeError as e:
        # Catching this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'union'
        df_catalogs_and_databases = _df
    except Exception as e:
        raise

display(df_catalogs_and_databases)
```